# Add search field

Tags: php, search

```
<form method="post" action="oabtest.php?go" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<p><a href="?by=A">A</a> | <a href="?by=B">B</a> | <a href="?by=C">C</a> |<a href="?by=D">D</a> |<a href="?by=E">E</a> |<a href="?by=F">F</a> |<a href="?by=G">G</a> |<a href="?by=H">H</a> |<a href="?by=I">I</a> |<a href="?by=J">J</a> |<a href="?by=K">K</a> |<a href="?by=L">L</a> |<a href="?by=M">M</a> |<a href="?by=N">N</a> |<a href="?by=O">O</a> |<a href="?by=P">P</a> |<a href="?by=Q">Q</a> |<a href="?by=R">R</a> |<a href="?by=S">S</a> |<a href="?by=T">T</a> |<a href="?by=U">U</a> |<a href="?by=V">V</a> |<a href="?by=W">W</a> |<a href="?by=X">X</a> |<a href="?by=Y">Y</a> |<a href="?by=Z">Z</a> </p>

<p>You may also search by Patrol.</p>
<form method="post" action="oabtest.php?go" id="searchform">
    <input type="text" name="patrol">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>
<?php
//Include database connection details
require_once('config.php');

//Array to store validation errors
$errmsg_arr = array();

//Validation error flag
$errflag = false;

//Connect to mysql server
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "*****", "*****");
if (!$link) {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
}

//Select database
$db = mysql_select_db("troop97_***");
if (!$db) {
    die("Unable to select database");
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
        if (preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['name'])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];


//-query the database table
            $sql = "SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM contact WHERE First_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "%' OR Last_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "%'";
//-run the query against the mysql query function
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

//-count results

            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            echo "<p>" . $numrows . " results found for " . stripslashes($name) . "</p>";

//-create while loop and loop through result set
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
                $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
                $ID = $row['ID'];

//-display the result of the array

                echo "<ul>\n";
                echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"oabtest.php?id=$ID\">" . $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name . "</a></li>\n";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<p>Please enter a search query</p>";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['by'])) {
    $letter = $_GET['by'];

//-query the database table
    $letter = mysql_real_escape_string($letter);
    $sql = "SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM contact WHERE First_Name LIKE '" . $letter . "%' 
OR Last_Name LIKE '" . $letter . "%'";

//-run the query against the mysql query function
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

//-count results
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo "<p>" . $numrows . " results found for " . $letter . "</p>";

//-create while loop and loop through result set
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
        $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
        $ID = $row['ID'];

//-display the result of the array

        echo "<ul>\n";
        echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"oabtest.php?id=$ID\">" . $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name . "</a></li>\n";
        echo "</ul>";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['go'])) {
        if (preg_match("/[A-Z | a-z]+/", $_POST['patrol'])) {

            $patrol = $_POST['patrol'];



//-query the database table
            $patrol = mysql_real_escape_string($patrol);
            $sql = "SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM contact WHERE Patrol LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($patrol) . "%'";

//-run the query against the mysql query function
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

//-count results
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

            echo "<p>" . $numrows . " results found for " . $patrol . "</p>";

//-create while loop and loop through result set
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
                $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
                $ID = $row['ID'];

//-display the result of the array

                echo "<ul>\n";
                echo "<li>" . "<a href=\"oabtest.php?id=$ID\">" . $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name . "</a></li>\n";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }

        if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
            $contactid = $_GET['id'];

//-query the database table
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE ID=" . $contactid;


//-run the query against the mysql query function
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

//-create while loop and loop through result set
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

                $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
                $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
                $Home_Phone = $row['Home_Phone'];
                $Cell_Phone = $row['Cell_Phone'];
                $Work_Phone = $row['Work_Phone'];
                $Email = $row['Email'];
                $Home_Street = $row['Home_Street'];
                $Home_City = $row['Home_City'];
                $Home_State = $row['Home_State'];
                $Home_Zip = $row['Home_Zip'];
                $Troop_Role = $row['Troop_Role'];
                $Patrol = $row['Patrol'];

//-display the result of the array

                echo "<ul>\n";
                echo "<li>" . $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name . "</li>\n";
                echo (empty($Home_Phone)) ? '' : "<li>" . $Home_Phone . " Home</li>\n";
                echo (empty($Cell_Phone)) ? '' : "<li>" . $Cell_Phone . " Cell</li>\n";
                echo (empty($Work_Phone)) ? '' : "<li>" . $Work_Phone . " Work</li>\n";
                echo "<li>" . "<a href=mailto:" . $Email . ">" . $Email . "</a></li>\n";
                echo "<li>" . $Home_Street . "</li>\n";
                echo "<li>" . $Home_City . ", " . $Home_State . " " . $Home_Zip . "</li>\n";
                echo "<li>" . $Troop_Role . "</li>\n";
                echo "<li>" . $Patrol . "</li>\n";
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### SQL Injection Risk

If you ever use a value from a submitted form when interacting with a database, you should escape the content before doing so. In MySQL, the best function to do this is `mysql_real_escape_string()` [PHP Manual](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
$sql="SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM contact WHERE First_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) . "%' OR Last_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) ."%'";
```

### Adding Fields to Search

If you are wanting to add an additional field, like "Department" to the search query, you simply have a field on the search form corresponding to it, and then adapt your SQL Search to have it included in the `WHERE` clause:

```
$sql="SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name
      FROM contact
      WHERE ( First_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) . "%'
              OR Last_Name LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string( $name ) ."%' )
            AND Department='" . mysql_real_escape_string( $department ) ."'";
```

### Using One Field for Two Searches

If you wanted to use a single text field to perform the above search, you will need to decide on some kind of prefix for users to prefix the value for the second field with.

For instance, if we specify "**in:**" as a prefix to designate the Department, so a search for "**John in:Radiology**" would look for any person with a first, or last, name starting with "**John**" but only those in the "**Radiology**" department.

```
list( $name , $department ) = explode( ' in:' , $_POST['name'] , 2 );
```

instead of

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

### LIKE Search Limitation

At the moment, your code will only search for First Names and/or Last Names which start with the entered value. You can make the search return either fields which simply contain (not just start with) the entered value by putting another "%" at the start of the search string:

```
$sql="SELECT ID, First_Name, Last_Name FROM contact WHERE First_Name LIKE '%" . $name . "%' OR Last_Name LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";
```

### Full-Text Search

You may want to look at this tutorial - [Using MySQL Full-text Searching](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304). It covers the concepts of Full-Text Searching, will allows you to find one, or more, words submitted through a single field across multiple database fields.

### Limit Returned Rows

Always a good idea to limit the number of rows you return for a search, whether you paginate or simply show X rows. Failing to do this would allow a malicious user to essentially scrape your whole database by simple searching for each letter of the alphabet.

Comment: While I do not know wrt. multibyte characters he is using pregmatch on letters only, which should prevent any SQL injection. But yes using mysql_real_escape is usually a good thing. Alternatively using a prepared statement is much better and faster.

Comment: @dmwesq, that's what I meant by filtering user inputs. User input is your enemy, don't trust it. :)

Comment: A few questions and comments - I purposely don't want to return names unless they start with the letters listed which is why I don't have the extra wild card. However, won't adding the extra field (such as department) with AND only return those names in that department that start with the letters used? I am looking to have a separate return of all people in the department regardless of the spelling of their name? I also would want if possible to be able to search from the single search field on the form (if that matters). What I have tried has not worked.

Comment: In addition, how does one limit the return rows as you suggest?

Comment: @dmwesq: See my amended answer for a solution where you can use one field to search two fields independently. To limit the number of rows returned, you simply append " LIMIT 25" to the end of your SQL Query (to limit it to the first 25 rows). Of course, if you are searching with rather vague terms, it will indiscriminately show only the first 25 rows (unless you apply a sorting order). Again, Full-Text Search & Boolean Searching allows you to rank the returned results by relevance/match strength, which is, again, a good point for using it (especially when limiting the returned results).

Answer (score 0):

Add your hypothetical field say `search_field` and then search for it with `"SELECT * FROM contact WHERE search_field='search value' order by First_Name"`, don't forget to index on `search_field` if it is going to be a unique field like email. I hope the code you pasted above will not go into production. Do not trust user inputs and filter them properly before you used them in SQL queries, needless to say store db credentials and connection string in a separate file and include it.

Comment: Pardon me as I'm new to all of this - I assume you mean to put the username, password, etc in a separate file and include the file (i.e config.php) in my man file? I have read elsewhere where they suggest not breaking apart into multiple files. Very confusing as there is obviously many ways to accomplish the same task and hard to know what is best. Also, what do you mean by "don't forget to index" on the new field?

Comment: The way you talk I guess you are not a full time programmer, please forgive me If I sound offensive, m not good with words :D, my simple rule of engineering is to make things modular, its easy to locate the faulty module & fix or replace it with better one, in similar way placing user/pass in config will help. Another point raised is SQL injection, its a serious thing, don't overlook it. Last, if you want to search something in table it is advisable to have it indexed. Given the limited scope of this comment box all I can tell you it will speed up the search.

Comment: I am certainly not a full time programmer. I do maintain 2 sites and am always striving to add better functionality to them, and have spent a lot of time reading and trying to learn. Believe me I am not just asking questions here - I am looking in many different sources but still find all of this quite challenging. Having said that, I am still trying to get this to work. I started a new file with my second search component in it, and once that worked I brought over some of that code to this file. I'm sure it is not correct, but I did manage to get the search form to display correctly.

Comment: I also managed to get all the search methods to properly display the initial results of names that meet the search criteria. Now the part that doesn't function is to pull the full information for any given ID from the database. Instead, I get returned to my search form when I try to display the additional info. Any help would be appreciated. I know I may still have some sql injection issues to work on, but at least I hope to get the form working right before tacking that part of the problem. I have edited the original post with the current code.

Comment: @dmwesq, hey even am not a CS student, learned by doing. Thats the best way to learn. You are doing good job. If you could share the code I or someone else can help you here.

Comment: Code was put into main post above

Comment: Appreciate the cleaner looking code, but any idea on where the problem lies?

Comment: Is it possible that there is no solution to this other than having the two searches in two separate files?

Comment: @dmwesq, on a first look I can say it can be done in single file, I will spare some time in the evening but `oabtest.php?go` can be changed to `oabtest.php?go=searchbynameonly` and `oabtest.php?go=searchbyotherfieldbutsortbyname` and so on and on submit check what `$_GET['go']` is either switch through it or use `if else`, I am all tied up with meetings and training sessions :-(

Comment: Thanks - can't say I understand though. My name search returns the proper names and my other field (which is called patrol) returns all names in the patrol. So the entire code works properly until I get to the point of trying to then display the additional information by contactID. What then is the purpose of changing the name of the action?

Comment: Just checking for any updates on this - I'm spending hours but going nowhere and it is totally baffling to me.